# How can I stop the momentary redirect with the #_=_ on the url when using Facebook Oauth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport.js

I'm using Passport and Angular to log in to a site via Facebook. Code looks like:

```
  facebookStrategy: function() {
    if (!process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID) {
      throw new Error("A Facebook App ID is required if you want to enable login via Facebook.");
    }
    if (!process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET) {
      throw new Error("A Facebook App Secret is required if you want to enable login via Facebook.");
    }
    return new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL || ("http://localhost:" + process.env.PORT + "/auth/facebook/callback")
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      var user;
      user = module.exports.findOrCreateOauthUser(profile.provider, profile.id);
      done(null, user);
    });
  }
```

(`http://localhost`? crap, need to fix that, this is some sample code that I'm adapting)

OK so the solution to this is (jade):

```
script(type="text/javascript").
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('#_=_') > 0) {
      window.location = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/, '');
  }
```

That seems fine, but it's an unnecessary redirect. So the perfectionist in me would like to get rid of it. The docs seem to say that `redirect_uri` is needed here, but I have `callbackURL` and Passport Facebook lib [seems to think they're the same](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/71). Still getting the redirection to the meaningless URL even when using `callbackURL`.

Specifically I want to know if it's possible to fix this via Passport instead of page-side javascript that fixes the url. The latter seems hacky.

Comment: location.replace() is faster than re-assigning the whole url, and changing location.hash won't navigate at all. you can also use history.pushState() to change the whole url without navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on Facebook's side, not Passport's.  You can't change the hash server-side, so adding this snippet at the top of your JS will do the trick (no need for a redirect):

```
if (window.location.hash === '_=_') {
  window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Per the author of [Passport-Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook):

> Facebook's OAuth 2.0 implementation has a bug in which the fragment
>   #_=_ is appended to the callback URL. This appears to affect Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari. This fragment can be removed via
>   client-side JavaScript, and @niftylettuce provides a suggested
>   workaround [there is a link]. Developers are encouraged to direct their complaints to
>   Facebook in an effort to get them to implement a proper fix for this
>   issue.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I want to fix this without the page-side javascript. Facebook is appending the `_=_` because the redirect_uri isn't present. But it seems like it is in the code. So perhaps this is a bug in passport.

Comment: You are correct. If you don't mind, I appended some text explaining it.

Comment: @jcollum No problem, thanks!  Should help those finding this answer in the future.